# How to decode Tx data? Online tool?

Tags: abi, calldata, data-types, decoding

Is there a fast way to decode the data returning from a Smart Contract call? I know there are github projects with JS libraries to decode this kind of data (such as https://github.com/ConsenSys/abi-decoder ), but is there any faster receipt to do it without installing external code? Some kind of online tool to provide the decoding?

The data I need to decode is like this:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a0
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005c4742b7
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005c475452
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000018b
5b22303333356363306431663939646238663937356166666532613235326565
3761383837313635646536383738643063303464613330313862636135643661
3331363266323837663431616366663033616362373734633666666130646239
6634333230616566626262663761313766306263303162613232313633303630
3963613932633561663537323865623466643064346333376133343234613337
3430333261613465323037393136656235633839643963306137396539306666
63383261222c2230333335636330643166393964623866393735616666653261
3235326565376138383731363564653638373864306330346461333031386263
6135643661333136326632383766343161636666303361636237373463366666
6130646239663433323061656662626266376131376630626330316261323231
3633303630396361393263356166353732386562346664306434633337613334
3234613337343033326161346532303739313665623563383964396330613739
653930666663383261225d000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000018b
5b22303333356363306431663939646238663937356166666532613235326565
3761383837313635646536383738643063303464613330313862636135643661
3331363236336138303230323663343437373139353364616161323437303734
6136323163316535393938313737613836643437386532623332373864613465
3061353531373833663061393132333532343662313837653862363962376366
3864656537613639323564623663303864383339313332613933366635363662
36646239222c2230333335636330643166393964623866393735616666653261
3235326565376138383731363564653638373864306330346461333031386263
6135643661333136323633613830323032366334343737313935336461616132
3437303734613632316331653539393831373761383664343738653262333237
3864613465306135353137383366306139313233353234366231383765386236
3962376366386465653761363932356462366330386438333931333261393336
663536366236646239225d000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

On a first sight I guess there are two uint256 and two strings in there, but a more accurate decoding is needed.

Any help will be appreciated. Thx!

Comment: You need to have the ABI file of the smart contract and then decoding is easy, you can even do it by a hand.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Yeah.. But how??

Comment: Using Web3 library for your programming language

Comment: You could try https://calldata.swiss-knife.xyz/decoder?calldata= or https://tools.deth.net/calldata-decoder